# json from java with multiple values

Tags: java, android, json, http

I have to send a json string to a server, with this sintax:

```
"id":"00",
"action":"register",
"get_value":"true",
"values":{
            "user":"Jack", 
            "password":"Jhonson", 
            "id":"123456" 
        }
};
```

I have some problems with the values field, I don't know how to set them in a http request.

can someone makes me an example to how send this json string to a server?

thanks!

Comment: can't you use `POJO`

Comment: I don't know what is POJO :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try {
        JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
        myObject.put("id", "00");
        myObject.put("action", "register");
        myObject.put("get_value", "true");
        JSONObject values = new JSONObject();
        values.put("user", "Jack");
        values.put("password", "Jhonson");
        values.put("id", "123456");
        myObject.put("values",values);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then use `myObject.toString();` to send the content to the server

Answer (score 0):

Please set this json in `httpPost.setParams(your_jsonstring);`

Answer (score 0):

Prepare Json Object from data :

```
try{
     JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject();
     mainJsonObject.put("id", "00");
     mainJsonObject.put("action", "register");
     mainJsonObject.put("get_value","true");

     JSONObject valueJsonObject = new JSONObject();
     valueJsonObject.put("user", "Jack");
     valueJsonObject.put("password", "Jhonson");
     valueJsonObject.put("id","123456");

     mainJsonObject.put("value",valueJsonObject);
 }catch (JSONException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Add json data to StringEntity as String:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(mainJsonObject.toString());
```

Set StringEntity to httpPost :

```
httpPost.setEntity(se);
```